# False 3D programming without OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, 2d

I'm actually looking after technical solutions to program a study assistant for the game of Go. What annoy me in existing programs is tha fact that the real life perspective of the player's eye looking at a Goban isn't respected.

GlGo exists, but while the number of stones increases, the rendering dramatically slows down due to the number of stones, disabling to possibility to add frames with statistical information on to of the Goban, that would break the real-timeness of the application.

So, my Question is:
Would it be possible to realize an interpolation of a simple 2D Goban to make the board & stones looks-like 3D, but without 3D rendering engine? The board movement would only be along one axis.

Comment: If you have a fixed viewport, you can use a sprite sheet - two sprites for each row.

Comment: I think even with 100.000 Stones OpenGL should not slow down.

Comment: It really depends on how effective the rendering is (e.g. (not) using VBOs etc.) and the complexity of the stones (high polygon models :)).

Comment: @Mario Of course, if you are using the fixed function pipeline it may be much slower, but cmon even 5.000 stones should not slow down the application. Something is really going wrong here!

Comment: IF he managed to make lags in such lightweight scene... It will lag even in isometry. Most likely renderer fall in to software mode or something. I even dont know. Or those stones have like 1k polygons each and rendered with ray tracing :P

Comment: +1 to Felix K. The reason for asking this question is *issues* with a 3D rendering implementation, not fundamental problems with 3D rendering in general. Changes are these issues will repeat themselves in the suggested 2D isometric implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly: All you have to do is doing the 3D to 2D transformation. Then simply draw your stones using sprites. If you scale them, you only need a white and a black one.

As for transformation, a simple one could be something like this:

```
x = left_border + board_x * gridwidth;
y = top_border + board_y * gridwidth / 2;
```

If you want perspective etc. it's getting a bit more complicated, but in general it shouldn't slow you down significantly unless you're doing something wrong.